# Why is there a comma before "locally accredited" in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation

The following sentence is clipped from news. I don't quite understand the reason to have a comma before "locally accredited.

> Only students pursuing ­full-time, locally accredited ­self-financing undergraduate programmes in Hong Kong ­offered by select institutions would be eligible for the HK$30,000. Such programmes ­often cost HK$70,000 or more.

Comment: The comma is there because the writer wanted to insert a pause in a long list of modifiers. He might also have added one after _accredited._ It's entirely and only a matter of the writer's style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author has the comma after

> ­full-time

so the reader does not read:

> full-time locally

and pause to wonder what that might mean.

> Self-financing undergraduate programmes

are

> full -time

and

> locally accredited

but not

> full-time locally accredited

. "Full-time" has nothing to do with accreditation; the comma prevents association with "full-time" and "accredited" The comma makes the reading easier, and should be there.

Comment: This's true. This avoided ambiguous meanings.